# Implementation of an Adaptive Normalization method

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, r, normalization

Referencing: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.718.9985&rep=rep1&type=pdf

I'm trying to wrap my head around the method described in this paper

I currently have 2 main questions:

1. In the equation for R[i] on page 4, does the top row become S[0] when i = 1? If so, what is S[0]? And if not, how should it be calculated then?
2. Table IV on page 5, could someone explain how the table is derived? As well as why the paper goes from a single sequence in Table III to multiple sequences in Table IV?

Answer (score 1):

I am reading for this paper today. I am not sure my answer whether can help you.

Q1: See the defination of i, which is [1, n-k+1], so the index i in equation is begin from 1, not 0. If you use python to calculate, you need to reduce 1 index and begin from 0, but it doesn't matter if you use Matlab. To calculate S[1](it means your S[0]), S[1] = 1 / k * sum(i, i+k-1).

Q2: In this part, I think there are some problems in the paper description. "In the experiments reported in Section IV, we used the value 3.0." I use the value 3.0 calculate the quantile range is (0.966, 1.038). If use 1.5, the result would be (0.981, 1.022). Now, I just derive the Table IV is the same as the paper, but the Table V is a little different. I try many times, There is still some different. So I think there is some problem in the paper.

If you want to discuss with me, I could share my code to you to discuss it.

Comment: Table IV I calculated.
[[1.008 0.999 0.992 0.992 1.008 1.015]
 [0.995 0.987 0.988 1.003 1.01 1.009]
 [0.984 0.985 1.001 1.007 1.006 1.014]
 [0.98 0.996 1.002 1.001 1.01 1.005]
 [0.994 1.001 0.999 1.008 1.003 1.002]
 [1.0 0.999 1.007 1.003 1.002 1.01]
 [0.995 1.004 0.999 0.998 1.006 1.001]
 [1.004 0.999 0.998 1.006 1.001 1.013]]

Comment: Table V I calculated
[[0.6 0.086 -0.314 -0.314 0.6 1.0]
 [-0.143 -0.6 -0.543 0.314 0.714 0.657]
 [-0.771 -0.714 0.2 0.543 0.486 0.943]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [-0.2 0.2 0.086 0.6 0.314 0.257]
 [0.143 0.086 0.543 0.314 0.257 0.714]
 [-0.143 0.371 0.086 0.029 0.486 0.2]
 [0.371 0.086 0.029 0.486 0.2 0.886]]

Comment: Can you share the code please?